# Coffeescript changes constructor's parameter name

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm facing a very weird behavior of coffeescript compiler. While working with angularjs in coffee it is changing the parameter name inside a class constructor. This causes a fault in angular's injector.

I've solved by using a different architecture. My question here is: WHY is this happening, WHY does coffeescript compiler considers necessary to change that name since they are in different scopes??

```
app = angular.module 'test', []

app.config ($q) ->
   ### do something with $q ###

app.service 'serv', 
  class MyServ

    ### constructor saves $q into this, BUT...###
    constructor: (@$q) ->

    ### func uses $q ###
    func: ->
      @$q.when 'ok'
```

Compiles to:

```
var MyServ, app;

app = angular.module('test', []);

app.config(function($q) {

  /* do something with $q */
});

app.service('serv', MyServ = (function() {

  /* constructor saves $q into this, BUT... */
  function MyServ($q1) {
    this.$q = $q1;
  }


  /* func uses $q */

  MyServ.prototype.func = function() {
    return this.$q.when('ok');
  };

  return MyServ;

})());
```

If I remove the usage of $q in previous function (`config`), then it works as expected.

Also if not using `@` inside constructor it works too.

Is this some kind of a bug or is legit?

Comment: The problem is that the `@$q` parameter to the constructor is being renamed to `$q1`, right?

Comment: yes, do you know why?

Comment: Check the CoffeeScript [CHANGELOG](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog), there was something about renaming parameters. I'm sure I've seen this come up CoffeeScript and Angular before. You could probably switch to `constructor: ($q) -> @$q = $q` if you have to.

Comment: Why would you expect it to use the variable `$q`?  You asked for it to be `@$q`, which it did.  The name of the temporary variable that's necessary because js doesn't allow that construct seems pretty irrelevant.

Comment: Angularjs uses the parameter name for dependence injection, since `$q1` does not exist it fails. For any other situation I agreed with you that change seems irrelevant, so, my original question is: Why coffescript decided to rename that parameter? In what situation this is necessary? Could that be a bug?